# why the python url open get page source was different from google chrome

Tags: python, html

I am using this code in Python 3 to get the webpage source code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "http://tool.liumingye.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=Unstoppable"
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    html_page = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
    popup_modal = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "modal-body"})
    print(str(popup_modal))
```

but the `modal-body` class was not found in the result of html source code fetched by Python request, in the google chrome I can found the class `modal-body`. Why the google chrome result different with the Python request? what should I do to make the result keep the same? This is the google chrome source code and could found the `modal-body`:

[image]

I also tried to use curl to find the `modal-body`, but there is no result:

```
curl "http://tool.liumingye.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=Unstoppable"|grep modal-body
```

what should I do to get the `modal-body` class html content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your destination url `http://tool.liumingye.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=Unstoppable` is a dynamic WPA application. That creates HTML elements dynamically after finished loading and interacting with the user.

Therefore it is possible your script/program should wait few seconds. Letting the page to load into the virtual-browser/web client. And then inspect it iterativly.

Assuming your web client will receive the information after the page loaded.

Comment: I am tried to use a headless google chrome to get the content, but I am not sure it works. I am trying....@Dudi Boy

Answer (score 1):

You can create a persistent session and parse the content using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
t = s.get('http://tool.liumingye.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=Unstoppable')
html = BeautifulSoup(t.content)
```

I am not able to find `modal-body` in both from Chrome DEV or the returned request but the results are identical for me.

Comment: The google chrome could found the `modal-body`@BernardL

Answer (score 0):

I am use this code to fetch the full source code right now, it contains the `modal-body`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class FetchMusic:

    def __init__(self):
        print("fetch...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    # driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get('http://tool.liumingye.cn/music/?page=audioPage&type=migu&name=Unstoppable')
    results = driver.page_source
    for result in results:
        print(result.text)
```